# How to build Angular 2 Dev & Production Build with Gulp for Express Application?

Tags: express, angular, gulp

I am using ExpressJS with view engine 'ejs'. Now I'm adding Angular2. Earlier I was using GULP for my build automation. How can I add gulp tasks to generate production build as well as dev build with sourcemaps.

I've searched lot many but I can't figure out what will be the tasks.

Project structure is like:

```
-- Project
  |-- Client
     |******
     |-- //ALL ANGULAR TS FILES
  |-- Server
     |-- public/js // I want my compiled Angular2 files to be here.
     |-- //ALL SERVER RELATED FOLDERS
  |--gulpfile.js // I want to write tasks here to take all client ts files and compile them to js and put them in server/public/js folder
```

Comment: Have you checked out the Angular CLI? It does all this for you without you having to do anything. It's the recommended way of working with Angular 2.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I checked it, but I'm already using gulp and I don't want to move and depend on npm scripts.

Comment: But you're already depending on npm scripts if using gulp.. You should depend on npm scripts because they help your development, they don't affect anything in production.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I want to use gulp for my personalised tasks. I would like to keep everything on one track.